# Laravel 5 - Handling different data within Controller

Tags: laravel-5

I have a system whereby you can go and create different documents.  From a select list, I could select for instance Project Brief, and this would display the Project Brief form to me whereby I could add data to complete a project brief.  I could also select other documents from the select, and the form displayed to me would be appropriate for the chosen document.

One issue I had was I had created a new database table for each document type, and also a new Model, Controller etc.  I knew this was going to get out of hand if I created many types of documents, so I decided to change things a bit.  My new database design is like so
[image: Database design]

So I am making a generic documents table which I can use to make different documents.
I was hoping now to have a generic Document Model, so I do not need a new Model for each type of Document.  The project I am facing is this.  From within my projects page, I have a drop down menu where you can select the type of document you want to create.  One example is this

```
{!! link_to_route('projects.projectBrief.create', 'Project Brief', array($project->id)) !!}
```

The route for the above is as follows

```
Route::model('projects.projectBrief', 'Document');
Route::resource('projects.projectBrief', 'Docs\DocumentController', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
```

So it is using the project briefs view, but also using the generic Document Controller.  Now in my Document Controller, at the moment my create function is something like the following

```
public function create(Project $project)
{
    return View::make('projectBrief.create', compact('project'));
}
```

This is fine for this document, but because other Document types will use the same Controller, I need a way to separate things.  How would I go about doing this?  So if I chose Reporting Document from the select option, the above create method should return the view for the reportingDoc.  How can I determine what view to return?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of ways to do this, I would recommend adding documentType as a parameter in your link to the form.

```
{!! link_to_route('projects.projectBrief.create', 
    'Project Brief', 
    array('projectId' => $project->id, 'documentType' => 'projectBrief')) !!}
```

Note this will require making a change to your controller to pick up the named projectId and documentType parameters.